# Adding child node inside a XML node using C#

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my given XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Processes>
  <Process Name="Process1" Namespace="" Methodname="">
    <Validations/>
    <Transformations/>
    <Routings/>
  </Process>
</Processes>
```

I want to add new node *Validation* inside *Validations* and for that i have written the following code:-

```
XmlDocument originalXml = new XmlDocument();
originalXml.Load(@"C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\Process\Process1.xml");    
XmlNode Validations = originalXml.SelectSingleNode("/Processes/Process[Name="Process1"]/Validations");
XmlNode Validation = originalXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Validation",null);
Validation.InnerText = "This is my new Node";
Validations.AppendChild(Validation);
originalXml.Save(@"C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\Process\Process1.xml");
```

But, I am getting error in the line "Validations.AppendChild(validation)" as *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*. Please suggest some way to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\Process\Process1.xml");
var a = doc.Descendants("Validations").FirstOrDefault();
a.Add(new XElement("Validation", "This is my new Node"));
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\Process\Process1.xml");
```

Comment: great happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Your `SelectSingleNode()` didn't match any element, hence the null-reference exception. Beside the conflicting double-quotes problem, you should use `@attribute_name` pattern to reference attribute using XPath. So the correct expression would be :

```
originalXml.SelectSingleNode("/Processes/Process[@Name='Process1']/Validations");
```